# Configuring queue manager so that IBM MQ classes for JMS applications can connect in client mode

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I want to send a message to a queue in WebSphere MQ. For this I must create a server-connection channel definition as it is written in

[Configuring your queue manager so that IBM MQ classes for JMS applications](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031730_.htm)

But I don't know where I should input this command for creating channel:

```
CRTMQMCHL CHLNAME(JAVA.CHANNEL) CHLTYPE(*SVRCN)
TRPTYPE(*TCP)
MQMNAME( QMGRNAME )
```

Help me please in this question. And tell me please about the difference between client mode and binding mode.

Comment: I've assumed you're on the IBM i platform (aka iSeries aka OS/400) since you're asking about a command specific for that platform. However, it would be better if you added the platform you're using into your question details.

Answer (score 2):

The `CRTMQMCHL` is a CL command. This is specific to the IBM i platform (aka iSeries, aka OS/400). You can issue MQM CL commands from the Message Queue Manager Commands menu. To display this menu, type `GO CMDMQM` on the command line and press the Enter key.

If you wish to do this on a platform other than the IBM i platform (or from within the `RUNMQSC` CL command on IBM i) you can issue this command from inside a `runmqsc` command prompt.

To get a runmqsc command prompt, on an O/S command prompt type:-

```
runmqsc QMGRNAME
```

replacing *QMGRNAME* with the name of your queue manager. Then inside the runmqsc prompt that you now have, type:-

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(JAVA.CHANNEL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

**Client mode versus binding mode**
Client mode means you are connecting to the queue manager over the network, using a TCP socket.

Bindings mode means your application is running on the same machine as the queue manager, and the connection is made using a memory based inter-process communication (IPC) method, the JNI in th case of a Java application. You cannot use bindings mode if your application is running on a different machine than your queue manager.

**Further Reading**

- [Creating IBM MQ for IBM i objects](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q021600_.htm)
- [Connection modes for IBM MQ classes for JMS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031720_.htm)

Comment: Say me please, where in WebSphere MQ I can to establish my queue manager for client connection? Because if in my Java code I replace WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS with WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT my program throw exception.

Comment: That will rather depend on the exception. Search StackOverflow for the reason code you see in the linked exception and if you can't find an answer post a new question to more help. It's probably security failure, e.g. 2035 reason code.